# Reassign button doesn't send out email

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

Our Approval SharePoint workflow, reassign button doesn't send out email in Windows 10 environment. Any idea what caused this issue?

Comment: Are you getting any error message? Check your workflow history and let me know...

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the Start Approval Process workflow action? If you have enabled the “Send e-mail when ownership is assigned” option in task list (list settings > Advanced Settings), the approval workflow will send email to the user in Assigned To field.

When you reassigned the task, an email will be sent to the reassigned person, because a new ownership has been created in task list.

Answer (score 0):

When you start the approval workflow, Does it sends email to the assigned to user?

Make sure the user have valid email address.

Make sure you configure outgoing email successfully in your SharePoint farm.

Try to republish the Worklflow and compare the results.